# Subtle light-colored horizontal lines across Macbook screen, and jaw-dropping calibration behavior

Tags: macbook-pro, screen, color

### My issue:

When viewing solid, light tones, such as [#FDF6E3](http://www.color-hex.com/color/fdf6e3), I see evenly spaced horizontal lines across my entire screen (I have a 2010 white Macbook).

These lines are especially visible when the screen is viewed from below, or when the screen is tilted back.

### My attempted fix:

I decided to try to calibrate the colors on my screen (System Preferences -> Display -> Color -> Calibrate). I did not check the "Expert Mode" checkbox.

The first option presented to me is Gamma: I can select between:

1. Gamma 2.2 (Standard)
2. Gamma 1.8

**Regardless of the original value**, if I simply change the gamma selection, **the lines go away!** Yippee!!

So, I keep clicking "Continue", ignoring the other options, until I am asked to enter a name for my new color profile. I enter a name, and then the moment I click  "Continue", **the lines return**, and I'm told that new profile has been applied. Darn it.

Sure enough, if I change other settings, those settings do stick. So this isn't a matter of the color profile not getting applied.

### Question:

Has anyone experienced a similar issue? Why are the lines going away during the calibration process, but are immediately returning as soon as the new profile is applied? What should I do?

Comment: It certainly seems as a hardware problem, so if its still under warranty, you should visit an apple store asap!

Comment: +1 for getting it checked out.  If they try to tell you nothing's wrong with the machine, have them demo the same setup on another machine as proof.  If it also exhibits the behaviour, you're probably stuck with it.  Seems very odd IMO.

Comment: I did bring it to the Apple Store, and they immediately noticed the (admittedly subtle) problem. I am very, very used to having to insist that a product is defective, so I was shocked when an employee took a look at my screen and immediately said, "Yeah, that's an LCD problem". I'm currently waiting on its return.

Comment: ... and it came back with the same issue. Dammit.